# Prevent the junky prefix that comes with using TraceSource in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

I've just setup my project to use a TraceSource/TraceListener and added a default listener to log data to the output window using `new ConsoleTraceListener()`. I'm getting a lot of junky prefixes with every line. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
FluentFTP Verbose: 0 : InterNetwork: 123.123.123.123
FluentFTP Verbose: 0 : 421 Too many connections (8) from this IP
FluentFTP Verbose: 0 : Disposing FtpClient object...
FluentFTP Information: 0 : QUIT
```

I would like just the string that I trace:

```
InterNetwork: 123.123.123.123
421 Too many connections (8) from this IP
Disposing FtpClient object...
QUIT
```

The syntax I'm using is :

```
private static readonly TraceSource m_traceSource = new TraceSource("FluentFTP") {
    Switch = new SourceSwitch("sourceSwitch", "Verbose") { Level = SourceLevels.All }
};
...
m_traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceLevelTranslation(eventType), 0, message);
```

**Edit:** There are answers for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685581/tracelistener-headers-and-footers), [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2005/09/20/a-tracing-primer-part-ii-b-mike-rousos/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826211/how-does-system-tracelistener-prepend-message-with-process-name), but NONE of them cover the use case where you CANNOT modify the TraceListener, only the TraceSource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TraceListener headers and footers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685581/tracelistener-headers-and-footers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like that by explicitly writing to the trace source's listeners...and not calling TraceEvent. If you're willing to do that, you can do something like the following extension method. Note that it has to eat all exceptions thrown by the trace listeners:

```
static object traceSync = new object( );
static int traceMessageNumber;
internal static void Emit( this TraceSource traceSource, TraceEventType eventType, string message, params object[ ] args )
{
  try
  {
    lock ( traceSync )
    {
      var msgNum = Interlocked.Increment( ref traceMessageNumber );

      if ( traceSource.Switch.ShouldTrace( eventType ) )
      {
        //--> format your message like you want...
        var msg = YourMessageFormatter( msgNum, message, args );

        foreach ( TraceListener listener in traceSource.Listeners )
        {
          try
          {
            listener.WriteLine( msg );
            listener.Flush( );
          }
          catch { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    //--> maybe we'll write an event log entry?
  }
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
m_TraceSource.Emit( TraceLevelTranslation(eventType), message );
```